# Creating AlertDialog issue on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-alertdialog, android-context

Here I am again, I've found a lot of troubles developing my app, It was expected, I haven't programming on android ever Before
I'm not used to Views, Activities, Context and all that stuff yet, today, I'm having an issue creating a AlertDialog on my Fragment, I use Fragment
because I'm using a DrawerLayout.

The Error says:

> "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

here is my code

I declared a ViewGroup "context" variable to set the rootview value(OnCreateView method)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ventas_fragment, null);
    context = root;
```

The method where I try to create the AlertDialog is:

```
private void createDialog(int position){
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context.getContext());
    View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ventas_dialog,(ViewGroup) context.findViewById(R.id.ventaFragment));
    AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    db.setView(dialog_layout);
    db.create();
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)dialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            db.setTitle("Venta de Ponques - Cantidad");
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lanzador);
            db.setPositiveButton(R.string.aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(context.getContext(),"Prueba superada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            db.show();
            break;
}
```

}

which I call on:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
.....
gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            createDialog(position);
            }
        });
```

There error is detected on line

> db.show();

I've tried changing those context parameters on LayoutInflater.from() and AlerDialog.Builder() but It didn't work,
maybe the issue is no that complicated, but I don't really see it, I'm not understanding about the error, can anyone of you
guys give a hand and help me with this?

Thank you so much beforehand.

Comment: context = root; Im not sure you can do something like this..

Comment: You should use a dialog fragment instead and show that using childFragmentManager

Comment: CYrixmorten could you explain me wich a example please, I don't get your point, sorry :s, not understanding yet

Comment: I got this fixed, Following CYrixmorten recommendation